# Please fix this incorrect proof from Kunen

Tags: set-theory

To entertain myself, I've been (very, very slowly) working my way through Kunen's *Set Theory:  An Introduction to Independence Proofs* (1980 edition).  I've convinced myself that one of his proofs in the Martin's Axiom section of Chapter 2 is incorrect in a couple of places.  I think I've figured how how to patch one of the mistakes, but not the other.

First, the definition relevant to the mistakes:

> **Definition 2.4:**  Let $\langle \Bbb P, \leq \rangle$ be a partial order.  $D \subset \Bbb P$ is *dense* in $\Bbb P$ iff $\forall p \in \Bbb P \exists q \leq p(q \in D)$.  $G \subset \Bbb P$ is a *filter* in $\Bbb P$ iff

> (a)  $\forall p, q \in G \exists r \in G(r \leq p \land r \leq q)$, and

> (b)  $\forall p \in G \forall q \in \Bbb P (q \leq p \implies q \in G)$.

Now the mistakes:

> **Theorem 2.21:**  Assume MA($\kappa$).  Let $M_\alpha$, for $\alpha \lt \kappa$, be subsets of $\Bbb R$, each of Lebesgue measure $0$.  Then $\bigcup \{M_\alpha~\mid ~ \alpha \lt \kappa \}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

> **Proof:**  Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure.  Recall that a subset $M \subseteq \Bbb R$ has measure $0$ iff $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0$ there is an open $U \subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $M \subseteq U$ and $\mu(U) \leq \varepsilon.$  Fix $\varepsilon \gt 0$.  We shall find an open $U$ with $\mu(U) \leq \varepsilon$ and $\bigcup_{\alpha \lt \kappa} M_\alpha \subseteq U$.  Define

> $$\Bbb P = \{ p \subset \Bbb R~\mid ~ p \text{ is open } \land \mu(p) \lt \varepsilon \}.$$

> Define $p \leq q$ iff $q \subset p$; then $p$ and $q$ are compatible iff $\mu(p \cup q) \lt \varepsilon$ in which case $p \cup q$ is a common extension of $p$ and $q$.

> Intuitively, "$p$ forces $p \subset U$."  Formally, if $G$ is a filter in $\Bbb P$, let $U_G=\bigcup G$.  $U_G$ is clearly open.  We must also check that $\mu(U_G) \leq \varepsilon$.  First, note that if $p, q \in G$, they have a common extension $r \in G$ and since $r \leq p \cup q,$ $\color{red} {\text{ we have }p \cup q \in G.}$  Next, by induction on $n$, if $p_1, \ldots , p_n \in G$, then $p_1 \cup \ldots \cup p_n \in G$ and hence in $\Bbb P$, so $\mu(p_1 \cup \ldots \cup p_n) \lt \varepsilon$.  Thus, by the countable additivity of $\mu$, whenver $A$ is a countable subset of $G, \mu(\bigcup A) \leq \varepsilon.$

> $G$ is uncountable, but we now show that $\bigcup A = \bigcup G$ for some countable $A \subset G$; this will follow from the fact that the topology of $\Bbb R$ has a countable base.  Let $\mathscr B$ be the countable set of open intervals with rational endpoints.  If $x \in p$ for some $p \in G$, then there is a $q \in \mathscr B$ with $x \in q \subset p$.  Then $q \geq p$, $\color{red}{\text{ so } q \in G \text{ since } G \text{ is a filter.}}$  Thus, if $A = G \cap \mathscr B$, then $\bigcup A = \bigcup G = U_G$, so $\mu(U_G) \leq \varepsilon$.

The proof proceeds from there.  I can patch the first mistake.  Since the common extension $r \leq p \cup q$, it follows that $p \cup q \subseteq r$ so $\mu(p \cup q) \leq \mu(r) \lt \varepsilon,$ which is the result we need.  But I can't figure out how to patch the second mistake.

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks.

(Incidentally, this seems sufficiently clear, and the book was in such widespread use, that I can't believe I'm the first person to find this, but I haven't been able to find any on-line discussion of these errors.)

Comment: It is a known typo in Kunen's book that $q\le p$ should be $p\le q$ in condition (b) of the definition of filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mistake in the definition of filter. Condition (b) has to read:

> $\forall p\in G\forall q\in\Bbb P(\color{orange}{p\leq q} \implies q\in G)$

That is, a filter is closed upwards. I would personally add a condition (c) that says that a filter is nonempty, but this is not really important.

This should clarify the problems with the proof, but in case it doesn't here is some more:

---

In the proof, $\Bbb P$ is defined to be the set of opens in $\Bbb R$ with measure $<\epsilon$ ordered reversely by inclusion. A filter $F$ of $\Bbb P$ is a set of opens such that that any finite union $\bigcup p_i$ of opens $p_i\in F$ is also in the filter (this is what condition (a) gives us), and such that for any open subset $p\subset q$ (with $p\in \Bbb P$) of some open $q\in F$ we also have $p\in F$ (this is what (b) gives us).

So a stronger condition $q\leq p$ gives us a larger open set than $p$. This is what we want, since we want a large open set (so that it covers the union of all $M_\alpha$) that still has measure $\leq\epsilon$.

---

So the first mistake in the proof is not a mistake:

If $p,q\in G$, then they have a common $r\leq p$ and $r\leq q$. This is the same as saying $r\supset p$ and $r\supset q$. Clearly then $r\supset p\cup q$ as well, which means $r\leq p\cup q$. By point (b) from the definition of filter, then $p\cup q\in G$.

The second mistake follows directly from the corrected condition (b). Note that the set $\mathscr{B}$ of open rational intervals should be the set of open rational intervals with measure $<\epsilon$, since otherwise we cannot guarantee that $q\in \Bbb P$.

Comment: If that's the case then I need to go back and check all the prior proofs to make sure they still work.  But I'm really not sure that's where the problem lies.  Notice that given the definition of $\leq$, elements that are larger in the partial order are smaller as a matter of set containment.

Comment: @RobertShore That is exactly what I'm saying: a *stronger* condition is a *larger* subset. We say $p$ is stronger than $q$ if $p\leq q$, because $p$ "says more" about a filter than $q$.

Comment: Note that the definition of filter is quite commonly used in many areas of mathematics. The definition with the corrected mistake aligns with other uses of filters, and in general with the definition of a filter on a poset. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics). Since the order on $\Bbb P$ is the reverse of $\subset$, a filter on $\Bbb P$ as the poset is actually an *ideal* on the set structure of $\Bbb P$.